# Keep / append attributes to buffered PolyLines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, buffer, geopandas, pandas

I have a shapefile containing multiple line files with key attributes. I buffered each using cap_style=3 to get the correct buffer, but all of the attributes are lost. I'm either looking for added on code to retain the attributes from the original shapefile or a new script to append the old attributes to the new shapfile

```
lines= gpd.read_file(r"D:\brett\Documents\CAFE\Folder_Test3\Lines\Lines_comp\Lines_comp.shp")
Line_buffer = lines.geometry.apply(lambda g: g.buffer(1, cap_style=3))
line_buffer.to_file(r"D:\brett\Documents\CAFE\Folder_Test3\Lines\Lines_comp\Lines_buffer3.shp")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign buffered geometry as the geometry column of your GeoDataFrame. Note that you do not need `apply` to use `buffer`, GeoPandas has a built-in vectorized (performant) option for that.

```py
lines= gpd.read_file(r"D:\brett\Documents\CAFE\Folder_Test3\Lines\Lines_comp\Lines_comp.shp")
lines['geometry'] = lines.buffer(1, cap_style=3)
lines.to_file(r"D:\brett\Documents\CAFE\Folder_Test3\Lines\Lines_comp\Lines_buffer3.shp")
```

Comment: wow that worked almost perfectly, thank you! The only difference is that one of my columns which stored data as integers now reads it as a string, but I only needed that to be sorted for my prior processing and I think it should be fine now. I might play around with changing the column's / attribute's data type unless you know something off the top of your head.Either way thank you so much. I've been learning myself entirely to automate doing just this and every step I take forward includes a side step or a step back.